# POO e linguagens de programação

Tags: orientação-a-objetos

Vejo milhares de cursos falando sobre aprender programação orientada a objeto, mas quando se aprende POO você consegue aplicar aqueles conhecimentos em todas as linguagens que utiliza POO ou cada linguagem tem suas particularidades?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 5):

Consegue aplicar em todas as linguagens. Porém há algumas "escolas" de programação orientada a objeto. Então o que aprenderá em uma linha não se aplica bem em outra linha. As pessoas não concordam sobre o que é OOP, então cada linguagem pode ir por uma linha.

Recentemente dei uma palestra mostrando como a maioria dos recursos que as pessoas acham que são de OO em uma linguagem que todos dizem ser orientada a objeto e que na verdade são recursos de outros paradigmas. Inclusive mostro como OOP é um paradigma efetivamente pouco importante para engenharia e é forte só por causa do marketing.

Se as pessoas sequer sabem o que é OOP, sua terminologia correta, a forma real de aplicar (não exemplos simples e abstratos que não ensinam nada real), como vão conseguir fazer direito e ensinar direito? Se os conhecimentos estiverem errados ou distorcidos, consegue aplicar errado e de forma distorcida de todas as linguagens.

Eu não sei tudo mesmo tendo 30 anos de OOP, mas hoje entendo um pouco mais. Eu tenho vários *posts* aqui no site e estou refinando-os para tentar chegar em algo que faça mais sentido de forma ampla. Só uma dica: embora ainda se fala muito em OOP para muitos problemas ele não está sendo usado de forma intensiva mais, e as pessoas nem percebem.

Claro que os mecanismos mais específicos tem diferenças em cada linguagem, apenas o conceito geral é que é aproveitado.

> Eu ia colocar *links*, mas depois vi que a pergunta era duplicata, lá já está bem fundamentado.